# Dropwizard: How to stop service programmatically

Tags: java, dropwizard

To start the service, I know one uses `new MyService().run(args)`. How to stop it?

I need to start and stop programmatically for `setUp()` and `tearDown()` in my tests.

Answer (score 12):

You can start the service in new thread, once the test ends the service will shutdown automatically.

However starting in dropwizard 0.6.2 the dropwizard-testing module contains a [junit rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules) exactly for this use case ([see here](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/maven/dropwizard-testing/apidocs/com/yammer/dropwizard/testing/junit/DropwizardServiceRule.html)).

Usage of this rule will look something like this:

```
Class MyTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static TestRule testRule = new DropwizardServiceRule<MyConfiguration>(MyService.class,
                    Resources.getResource("service.yml").getPath()));

    @Test
    public void someTest(){
    ....
```

Comment: Why haven't they documented this class? (rhetorical) How did you find out about it, @LiorH? (not rhetorical)

Comment: yeah, that's strange it's not documented, hope it's not going to be removed. Someone at work pointed this class to me, don't know how he found it.

Comment: Hi @LiorH - nice to see you here! Very helpful ;)

Comment: This has been renamed / replaced with `DropwizardAppRule` (JUnit 4) and `DropwizardAppExtension` (JUnit 5).

Answer (score 11):

Keep the `environment` variable around and add the following method to your application:

```java
public void stop() throws Exception {
  environment.getApplicationContext().getServer().stop();
}
```

Now you can call `myService.stop()` to stop the server.

Comment: I found this very useful to stop the DW application if its running as a Windows service (using Apache Commons Daemon, for example).

Comment: Great solution. 
I have spent hours **without any luck** trying to use:
`environment.getApplicationContext().stop()`
`environment.getApplicationContext().destroy()`

**This one really works:**
`environment.getApplicationContext().getServer().stop();`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @LiorH for this great suggestion.

Here is a complete test class using the DropwizardServiceRule in **dropwizard-0.6.2**.

First create a service configuration for testing: `testing-server.yml` and place it in the test's class path (ex. `src\test\resources`).
This way you can set different ports for the test service to use:

```
http:
  port: 7000
  adminPort: 7001
```

A simple test class that checks if there is a resource at the location "/request" looks like this:

```
class TheServiceTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static DropwizardServiceRule RULE = new DropwizardServiceRule<MyConfiguration>(TheService.class,
            Resources.getResource("testing-server.yml").getPath());

    @Test
    public void
    dropwizard_gets_configured_correctly() throws Exception {
        Client client = new Client();

        ClientResponse response = client.resource(
                String.format("http://localhost:%d/request", RULE.getLocalPort()))
                        .get(ClientResponse.class);

        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
    }
}
```

I have also added the import in case you do not know what implementation to choose.

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardServiceRule;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
```

At the end of the tests, the server will shutdown gracefully, so you do not need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using stop() method of org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server, which is internally used by Dropwizard.

Comment: Can you please point me to some sample code? I do not understand how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you use this java feature in your main/constructor ...:

```
    // In case jvm shutdown
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // what should be closed if forced shudown
            // ....

            LOG.info(String.format("--- End of ShutDownHook (%s) ---", APPLICATION_NAME));
        }
    });
```