# Signal dropwizard to shutdown gracefully

Tags: embedded-jetty, dropwizard

Is there a way in which I can signal dropwizard app to stop embedded jetty servicing new requests, finish serving the existing requests and shutdown

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989008/dropwizard-how-to-stop-service-programmatically might help.

Comment: Will this method work in production ? And is there a built in mechanism provided by Dropwizard to do this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shutdownGracePeriod configuration option to wait for requests to complete before termination:

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/7eea09b60bacb8b3503cdddfb44df00d410058ad/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/AbstractServerFactory.java#L160-L167