# Dropwizard: How to shutdown service programmatically (in-process)?

Tags: java, dropwizard

What's the best practice to shutdown a Dropwizard service programmatically, e.g if an uncaught exception occurs in any thread I would like to terminate my Dropwizard service?

---

FYI: 
Similar but *unrelated* questions on StackOverflow:

This question [Dropwizard: How to stop service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989008/dropwizard-how-to-stop-service-programmatically) relates to unit testing your service

This question [How to shutdown dropwizard application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812816/how-to-shutdown-dropwizard-application) relates to how to shutdown your service out-of-process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any best practice out there yet.

```
System.exit(0);
```

This is what CTRL-C does. It calls the shutdown hooks and leads to graceful shutdown.

Comment: +1 - however, I would add that if you're like me and you are trying to do this inside of an actual HTTP resource (e.g. a protected admin resource that some sort of service dashboard might use to shut the service down) be sure you call System.exit(0) asynchronously (i.e. in a Future) or it won't actually shut everything down cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like the `DropwizardClientRule` and `DropwizardAppRule` do: Stop the Jetty service by calling `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#stop()`.

To get the Jetty instance, you'll have to register a lifecycle callback handler:

```
environment.lifecycle().addServerLifecycleListener(new ServerLifecycleListener() {
    @Override
    public void serverStarted(Server server) {
        myJettyServer = server;
    }
});
```